# How to find probability distributions for this Markov Chain

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, probability-distributions, markov-chains

The question is asking for the probability distribution of the next period if the current distribution is p<sub>3</sub> = 1, and all other p<sub>i</sub> = 0. I've read up on Markov Chains but I still don't understand how to go about solving this question. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You literally just plug your starting distribution $(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)$ into the equations:

$\begin{eqnarray} p'_1 & = & .5 \times 0 & + & .25 \times 0 & + & 0 \times 1 & &  & &  & &  & = & 0 \\
p'_2 & = & .5 \times 0 & + & .5 \times 0 & + & .25 \times 1 & &  & &  & &  & = & .25 \\
p'_3 & = & & + & .25 \times 0 & + & .5 \times 1 & + & .25 \times 0 & & & & & = & .5 \\
p'_4 & = & & & & & .25 \times 1 & + & .5 \times 0 & + & .25 \times 0 & & & = & .25
\end{eqnarray}$

and so forth.

Comment: This is the solution I found which is not the same as the one you gave above. https://imgur.com/Yi9nlyQ.

Comment: It seems you are multiplying $P$ by itself, you need to multiply $\mu^T$ by $P$ to get probability distribution, where $\mu$ is the given distribution vector.

Comment: That appears to be for a completely different distribution - specifically, (.5, .5, 0, 0, 0, 0) and I'm not sure why it's being used there.